# Fullcalendar - drag multiple external events - result represents 1 event on calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I would like to:

- Have checkboxes beside the external event
- Each external event that is checked, can be dragged together
- When the external events are dropped onto the calendar, one single event is added to the calendar.

I have done a lot of work with full calendar - but am not really sure where to even start with this. Is this a Fullcalendar problem/solution - or is it simply a javascript question?

I see a few posts - here at stack - about this topic, but I do not see any working examples or code.

A jsfiddle or something to that effect would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd have to write some code to make the checked elements into a single "draggable" object. Not really a fullCalendar specific thing, this would have to happen before you drop it on the calendar, especially if you want to drag them simultaneously. It's more something to look into around jQueryUI's "draggable" functionality, I think.

Comment: Hey you can use daypiloat calendar as well it has many features https://javascript.daypilot.org/scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related [Issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2253) on Fullcalendar to achieve multiple event drag drop. On the issue threads, user have accomplished the behavior of dragging and dropping multiple events on fullcalendar.

A working code of dragging external Events on calendar.

codepen.io/subodhghulaxe/pen/qEXLLr